# Call Api using WebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api

i am trying to call api using WebRequest, Api method is post following is my code.

```
string ContactUs = "https://nestiolistings.com/api/v1/clients/" + APIKey;
                var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ContactUs);
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic ############");
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.Accept = "application/json";

                JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

                List<people> list = new List<people>();
                people obj = new people();
                obj.first_name = model.Name;
                obj.last_name = model.Name;
                obj.email = model.Email;
                obj.phone_1 = "";
                obj.date_of_birth = "";
                list.Add(obj);
                RequestModel rm = new RequestModel();
                rm.people = list;
                rm.notes = model.Message;
                // string yourdata = jss.Deserialize<UserInputParameters>(stdObj);
                string yourdata = jss.Serialize(rm);
                StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
                requestWriter.Write(yourdata);
                requestWriter.Close();

                StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
                string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();

                responseReader.Close();
                request.GetResponse().Close();
```

But it gives all time 404 not found error.please some one help.

Comment: Copy the URL into your browser and navigate to it. If it gives 404 it means the URL is not valid.

Comment: if your check this URL: https://nestiolistings.com/api/v1/ its says 404

Comment: @NomiAli irrelevant - that's not the URL the OP is talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string ContactUs = "https://nestiolistings.com/api/v1/clients/" + APIKey;
```

I don't think you should be appending the API key to the URL. Say your key was `12345`, you'll end up with a URL like `https://nestiolistings.com/api/v1/clients/12345`.

That won't map to a valid resource in the API - the "clients" method is for creating clients, for that reason it doesn't accept specific Client IDs as extra route parameters (because the Client doesn't exist yet therefore doesn't have an ID), and even if it did and made logical sense to do so, your API key would, obviously, not match a valid Client ID.

The API Key should be provided in the authorisation header by the looks of it.

So:

```
string ContactUs = "https://nestiolistings.com/api/v1/clients/";
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ContactUs);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + APIKey);
```

(This is assuming that `APIKey` is already a base64-encoded string as required by the API).

See http://developers.nestio.com/api/v1/clients.html and http://developers.nestio.com/api/v1/auth.html for further information.

Comment: thanks for help.i tried this header but now it gives {"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."} error.

Comment: Forbidden is a permissions error (obviously). Is your API key definitely valid, and not expired? Did you create a string (including the : at the end as per the docs), and then make the `APIKey` object the result of that string formatted as base64, again as required by the docs?